# Tag/Mark Custom Street View

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have created a custom street view app using google maps api for an indoor store building, something similar to Comic Store View: http://www.bleedingcool.com/2011/11/02/google-street-view-enters-a-comic-shop/

But now my question is how do I tag/mark each and every product on the shelfs to show the prices in small text inside a div maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks cool, I am doing something kind of similar to this. One way to do it would be to add markers on the street view map at each product on the shelves and then check for the click. To add markers in street view check this out: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays

To check for a click read through this: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

So what you might want to do is create a custom marker image that is just a dotted line around a transparent center so that the user knows to click or hover there.